# How to fix the color of some variables in the scatter plot

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

[image]

In the above plot I want to fix the colors or major currencies like USD, AUD, CAD, EUR and rest can have random colors. How to achieve that? The no of currencies can vary.

```
fit <- lm(YVal ~ `Maturity Date`, data = filtered_data(), na.action=na.exclude)

p <- plot_ly(data = filtered_data(),  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers', 
             color = ~Crncy, colors = setNames(rainbow(nrow(filtered_data())), filtered_data()$Crncy),
             marker = list(opacity = 0.7, size=12) ,
             text = ~paste(" Security: ", filtered_data()$Security, "<br>",
                           "Currency: ", filtered_data()$Crncy, "<br>",
                           "YTM: ", filtered_data()$YTM,"<br>",
                           ifelse(filtered_data()$Floater=='Y',
                                  paste("DM: ", filtered_data()$YVal), 
                                  paste("ASW (USD): ", filtered_data()$YVal))
                           , "<br>", factor(filtered_data()$Sym))
                           ) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title="Maturity"), 
         yaxis = list(title="FRN: DM | Fixed: YAS ASW USD")) %>% 
  add_markers(symbol = ~factor(filtered_data()$Sym),color = I("black"), marker = list( opacity = 1, size=6)) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y = fitted(fit), showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this code, which sets up a specified vector for the focal ("fixed") groups and appends a rainbow palette for the rest (I haven't done anything about the possibility that the rainbow palette will clash with the fixed colours specified, but this should be a starting point)

```
fd <- filtered_data
fixed_col <- c(USD="blue", AUD="magenta", CAD="red", EUR="black")
all_grps <- unique(fd$Currency)
nonfix_grps <- setdiff(all_grps, names(fixed_col))
n_grp <- length(all_grps)
n_fix <- length(fixed_col)
```

Now combine the colour values and names of the fixed groups (first) and non-fixed groups (second)

```
col_vec <- c(fixed_col, rainbow(n_grp-n_fix))
names(col_vec) <- c(names(fixed_col), nonfix_grps))
```